# How can I create a "description" entitie with Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am currently making a dialog with Watson Assistant for a store, I need the asistant to be able to save the description of a product in a context variable using slots. The description should be a sentence of about 50 digits, any idea on how I can approach this?

Comment: You should add to the question of what you tried or the actual problem you encountered. I followed the steps from the documentation and it worked for me.